# Super simple spam program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

```
x = int(input("Choose the number of times you want to spam. "))

y = input("What message do you want to spam? ")

w = x + 1

for i in range(1,w):
    print(y)
```

Any way to make this program better? I'm currently learning Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Use descriptive variable names
2. No need to add one to x and then use `range(1, w)`  - get used to using [zero-based numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)
3. By convention in Python you can use `_` as the name for a loop variable when you won't actually be referring to that variable anywhere.
4. As you develop this into a full programme, structure code under functions.
5. use blank lines [sparingly](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines)

So:

```
def main():
    number_of_times = int(input("Choose the number of times you want to spam. "))
    message = input("What message do you want to spam? ")
    for _ in range(number_of_times):
        print(message)
```

Alternatively:

```
print((message + '\n') * number_of_times)
```